# Postgresql 9.4 and BDR SELECT bdr.bdr_group_join ERROR

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm trying to configurate Postgresql 9.4 with BDR, I have two servers where the master has the address 169.254.9.90 and the slave has the address 169.254.12.48. I have already configurated the master but when I try to join the slave to the replication I'm getting an error:

Command to join:

```
SELECT bdr.bdr_group_join(
    local_node_name := 'node2',
    node_external_dsn := 'host=169.254.12.48 port=5432 user=postgres dbname=amstest password=postgres',
    join_using_dsn := 'host=169.254.9.90 port=5432 user=postgres dbname=amstest password=postgres'
);
```

The error Im getting is:

> ERROR:  connection from remote back to local in replication mode
>   failed DETAIL:  remote reported: ERROR:  establish BDR: FATAL:  no
>   pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "169.254.9.90",
>   user "postgres", SSL on FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication
>   connection from host "169.254.9.90", user "postgres", SSL off
>
> DETAIL:  Connection string is 'replication=database
>   fallback_application_name='BDR test connection' connect_timeout=30
>   keepalives=1 keepalives_idle=20 keepalives_interval=20
>   keepalives_count=5   host=169.254.12.48 port=5432 user=postgres
>   dbname=amstest password=postgres'
>
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT *
>   FROM bdr.bdr_test_remote_connectback(join_using_dsn,
>   node_external_dsn)" PL/pgSQL function
>   bdr_group_join(text,text,text,text,integer,text[]) line 39 at SQL
>   statement

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "169.254.9.90", user "postgres"

Each node must be able to connect to each other node, both for replication and non-replication connections.

The newly joining node does not have a `pg_hba.conf` that permits the existing node you are specifying as a join target to connect to it.